# Facing Nosuchmethod error while calling jar file in JSR223 Postprocessor in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a jar file where i have one java class.I add that to jmeter and call that jar in sampler.When the request is hit I face java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for one of the methods inside that java class.That method doesn't need any maven dependencies as I use default java functions inside it.I tried manually including that jar to jmeter lib folder but no luck.
From my Java Maven framework,I have a baseclass where i have all my reusable functions.I convert this class into a jar file and load it in jmeter. I also convert my whole java project into a runnable jar file and load in jmeter.Now in one of my sampler,I have my JSR233 Postprocessor.i write groovy script and call the method inside that jar where my whole java project is bundled.So when i run that sampler my http request is hit and after that my jar will execute.
Now everything looks good.But when the code reaches the line where i call my reusable function from my baseclass,i get Nosuchmethod error. The java jar file is running properly in CMD and jenkins and also my java code is properly running in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing essential information like:

1. How does the function and the fully qualified class name look like
2. How exactly do you package the .jar
3. How do you call it from the JSR223 Sampler

If you have a runnable .jar and wait to invoke its "main" function programmatically from JMeter's JSR223 Test elements you will need to do something like:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        your.class.main('arguments here')
    }
}).start();
```

Demo:

[image]

If anything goes wrong in the majority of cases the reason or at least a clue can be found in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

More information on the concept of running functions from .jar files in JSR223 Test Elements - [How to Reuse Your JMeter Code with JAR Files and Save Time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-save-time)